# Get X levels from gee objects estimated in gee package

Tags: r

`glm` objects estimated using `stats::glm` in the base env have a convenient attribute for coded levels of factors, even character variables that are coded to factors based on alphabetical order of effects. This attribute is the `xlevels` slot and it is calculated with the invisible function `.getXlevels` that uses the model terms and the model frame.

Model frames are complicated and large objects that are difficult to calculate in retrospect.

I am using the `gee` package to obtain robust standard errors for model coefficients estimated with exchangeable correlation structures. I want to modify model output to show blank rows for factors with referent" levels. This is easy to do for `glm` objects, but for `gee` there is no `xlevels` attribute. What is the best way to obtain these levels from `gee` objects?

Example

```
library(gee)

n <- 300
x <- sample(letters[1:3], n, replace=TRUE)
w <- sample(letters[1:3], n, replace=TRUE)
y <- rnorm(n, ifelse(x=='a' | w == 'b', .4, 0))
i <- rep(1:12, each=25)

fit1 <- glm(y ~ x + w)
fit2 <- gee(y ~ x + w, id=i, corstr='exchangeable')

summary.glm2 <- function(obj) {
  out <- coef(summary(obj))
  lev <- obj$xlevels
  lev <- mapply(paste0, names(lev), lev)
  print(paste('XLEVELS ARE', paste(lev, collapse=', ')))
  lev[1, ] <- paste(lev[1, ], '(ref)')
  lev <- Reduce(c, lev)
  ind <- c(1, match(lev , rownames(out)))
  out <- out[ind, ]
  rownames(out) <- c('(Intercept)', lev)
  out
}

summary.glm2(fit1)
summary.glm2(fit2)
```

Comment: You would make this easier if you would pass a 'data' argument to regression functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not offering this as a finished solution because the usual way to find aout about what got passed to a regression function is to look within the 'data' argument. However, for your case:

```
> preds <-  attr(fit2$terms, "term.labels")
> sapply( preds, function(x)  unique(  get(x) )  )
$x
[1] "x"

$w
[1] "a" "c" "b"
```